# Is it possible to automate button clicks and text input in a web browser or a frame. Maybe even using a desktop tool if necessary?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, screen-scraping

I've been tasked with building a screen scraping application, and I'm looking for information on the best way to cope with web pages that would normally require user input and interaction.

Can this be done via standard web / javascript coding. Is there any API that would allow a desktop application to achieve the same effect?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selenium RC can do this: http://seleniumhq.org/

Comment: Nice. Can script in my own programming language too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Selenium IDE (firefox plugin) together with firefox for a simple easy and free solution

Comment: Using the IDE is not a good solution, Selenium RC is the one to use if you want any control over the screen scraping!

Comment: It all depends on the needs you have. selenium rc is alot bigger and more complicated and thus a complete waste if you can make do with selenium ide, but ofcourse selenium rc is the stronger of the two products.

Comment: I don't believe you can scrape an then store page contents from IDE, ie: scrape the page, parse a phone number and insert it into the db.

Comment: Yeah thanks. I'll be looking to use RC by the looks of things for the storage of contents.

Comment: You can quite easily do this using ajax - Selenium IDE is fully js based and it is trivial to add custom functionality like flow control and ajax calling from within it. I only ever need selenium rc when i need to do multiplatform smoketesting

Answer (score 0):

IRobotSoft Web Scraper is also a good choice.  See http://irobotsoft.com/help/.